# BLL and DLL are not founded, when I move them somewhere except source repos(Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have 3-layer MVVM project, my solution folder, DLL folder and BLL folder are inside 'source > repos >' and project loads normally
But if I move BLL or DLL(or both) to some other folder, or Desktop for example, my project doesn't load correctly and file moved to Desktop defined as not founded in solution explorer
How could I fix it? I need put all this three project folders(DLL, BLL, View) to one folder, because I need to share it as one big project, but I can't, because any movement with files or folder finishes with error 'Files not founded'
Sadly can not send images here, in y question(
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Open project file (.csproj) and check the path to other referring project in `ProjectReference`.

Comment: Are DLL and BLL just folders within one VisualStudio project, or are these independent projects (with their own csproj files)?

Comment: @KlausGütter It looks like these are 3 independent project folders with their own cproj files, but I don't understand why because I created it in one solution when I was making one big project

Comment: If these are projects within one solution, you should use "project references", not direct references to the produced assemblies (DLLs). Then VisualStudio knows how to build and reference the dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for that in your project: is it in the references list? If it is, check that it's built for the same CPU type as your project, and that the Reference properties option "Copy Local" is set to true.
If it isn't, try adding it. If that works, try rebuilding. If it doesn't, then it's probably a Native Library, and you need to ensure that the DLL is either in the EXE folder, or in a folder on the current PATH that Windows uses to locate executables.

Comment: It's not working after rebuild( But the problem is that Visual Studio even can not find my DLL and BLL when the're not in  'source > repos >' folder

Answer (score 0):

You Need to compile the DLL project into a dll file and then refer to the compiled dll file.

Or just use project references to add your DLL project and BLL project.

[image]

Comment: I have added this to my project and that's working fine, but I can not move BLL or DLL to other folder expect that where DLL and BLL were created, because in that case BLL and DLL are not founded

Comment: You need to add dependencies again, because your project will always try to find them where you added them.